# Looking for a way to trigger an event for testing custom event subscriber

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I am looking for ways to trigger an event in my local dev to check out a custom event subscriber. The actual event is triggered by Google social auth and I don't think it is possible to do that locally.

Is it possible to trigger events using devel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *event_dispatcher* service to trigger an event, for example with `\Drupal::service('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(MyModuleEvents::MY_EVENT, new MyModuleEventClass());`.

You need to replace `MyModuleEvents` and `MyModuleEventClass` with the class names you are effectively using, and `MyModuleEvents::MY_EVENT` with the effective event name. (It is better to use a class constant.)

You can run the code using `drush php "\Drupal::service('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(MyModuleEvents::MY_EVENT, new MyModuleEventClass());"`.

See [Subscribe to and dispatch events](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events) for more details.